# TFS compare (from windows explorer) opens file in older version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

When I right click on a file in windows explorer, and choose TFS > Compare > With Latest Version, it opens up visual studio 2012. How can I get it to open it with Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Have you installed the TFS 2013 Power Tools?  In particular, the Windows Shell Extensions?

Comment: Yes I have it installed

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a side-by-side installation at the moment. I would check:

- The installed Explorer TFS Menu Handler. (nice tool for this: Autoruns - sysinternals.com)
- The environment variables PATH and TFSPowerToolDir.
- Related Registry entries.

Comment: I updated the TFSPowerToolsDir PATH variable, but it didn't fix it. Will look into the others